# Porting Silverlight DataGridFrozenGrid to WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

Okay.
I want to transfer a number of templates from an Expression Blend Silverlight application to a WPF one.

All was going well until I came across DataFridFrozenGrid which is a Silverlight specific control. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.datagridfrozengrid%28VS.95%29.aspx) for more information.

The description is that it is a non-scrollable DataGrid.

Has anyone any experience of porting the same functionality as this to WPF?

Is it just a case of using DataGrid and setting properties to prevent scrolling or is more involved than that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've had no answers from people and so have spent my time producing a DataGrid template that produces much the same look.

Comment: could you please share your datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of this control; it's probably defined by the author of the templates you mentioned, look it up in the project you're converting or one of the referenced libraries.

Comment: It was introduced in Silverlight 3. I've put a link to the page on my original question

Comment: Ah, I see. It's an element used when you set some rows/columns to frozen. In that case it is part of the architecture of the Silverlight datagrid (it says it is only accessible through those styles and templates) and I doubt it would do you any good to try to port it to WPF, since there's no support for frozen rows/columns in the WPF datagrid that I can find.

Comment: Yes that's right. I was wondering whether I can replace it with a standard DataGrid control. I'll post back if I'm successful.